# Javascript submit()

Tags: javascript

I want to know how javascript submit works, but for the form i want to submit it needs to have a name attribute eg `name="create"`, how would i put that into the `submit()` function i want it to submit every 10 seconds like this:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload=function(){
            var auto = setTimeout(function(){ autoRefresh(); }, 100);

            function submitform(){

              document.forms["myForm"].submit('create');
            }

            function autoRefresh(){
               clearTimeout(auto);
               auto = setTimeout(function(){ submitform(); autoRefresh();},1000);
            }
        }
    </script>
```

I just need to know how to make it so it submits it with the `name="create"` not just the submit.

Comment: You might want to look into `setInterval()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following element to the form:

```
<input type="hidden" name="name" value="create">
```

Comment: It's important to note that more code would be needed to handle it. You may change the `value` to whatever is needed and then make an `if` statement to handle this later in the server-side code.

Comment: Yes. AFAIK, `.submit()` doesn't take any arguments, so that's being ignored.

Comment: sorry but how will this work? at all?
 <input type="submit" name="create" value="Create" />
i said i need to pass the name create not the value create

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish? What should it look like on the server?

Comment: Change the name and value to whatever you want.